# How to return documents of a collection without objectId in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

```
DB db = mongo.getDB("sample");
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("samplecollection");
DBCursor cursor2 = table.find();
```

gives the result as:
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "58bfbcff1d30d8a8c1194328"} , "ID" : 1 , "NAME" : "dgsdg"}

How to get the document without objectid?

Comment: not sure with an old version of the java-client, but with 3.2+ if you define a Document in your DB you can get the document from the DB which doesn't inlcude the ObjectId

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress a column in mongodb using Java drivers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418885/how-to-suppress-a-column-in-mongodb-using-java-drivers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `projection` for that.

Try this:

```
DBCursor cursor2 = table.find().projection(excludeId())
```

Read [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html) MongoDB documentation to know more.

Comment: when i do that it is showing error:                                                                                          Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to DBCursor

Comment: Sorry, there was some mistake, I have updated the answer and the link, please have a look

Comment: Iam getting the error "The method excludeId() is undefined for the type MongoData"

Comment: Is there any way to get the field types of the above document in java? http://stackoverflow.com/users/5084000/ravi-shankar

Comment: You mean the field type of all the fields in the document?

Comment: yes all the fields data types http://stackoverflow.com/users/5084000/ravi-shankar

Comment: i dont think there is any function to return the data types of all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this and worked:

```
MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("db");
     MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> contCol = database.getCollection("test");
     FindIterable<org.bson.Document> it = contCol.find().projection(excludeId());
     ArrayList<Document> docs = new ArrayList();


       for (org.bson.Document its : it) {
           System.out.println(its);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will be import this, import com.mongodb.client.model.Projections;

Then again, u try this one also..

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("hostName");
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("dbName");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("collectionName");
collection.withWriteConcern(new WriteConcern(1));
/*   whatever field you dosn`t need.. you will run this following code, 

        FindIterable<Document> findDoc = collection.find().projection(new Document().append("_id",0));  //if you need mean, you put _id value is 1.

    */
FindIterable<Document> findDoc = collection.find().projection(Projections.excludeId()) ;
 for (Document doc : findDoc) {
       System.out.println(doc);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the aggregation framework to achieve what you want:

db.getCollection('samplecollection').aggregate([{$project: { field1:1 ,field2: 1.....,'_id': 0} }])

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/